# How to copy specific rows from DataTable to another one

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable

I want to copy some rows of data table, to another one. I tried this code :

```
 DataTable Result = new DataTable();

    for(int i = 5; i < PageSize && i < TransactionDataTable.Rows.Count ; i++)
    {
        DataRow dr = (DataRow)TransactionDataTable.Rows[i];

        Result.ImportRow(dr);
    }

    string MobileNumber = TransactionDataTable.Rows[0]["MobileRegistration_MobileNumber"].ToString();
    string MobileNumber2 = Result.Rows[0]["MobileRegistration_MobileNumber"].ToString();

TransactionDataTable is a dataTable with more than 1000 rows.
```

in above code, MobileNumber has proper vallue, but MobileNumber2 dosent have. 
I got this error in last line ( in assigning MobileNumber2 value) :

```
Additional information: Column 'MobileRegistration_MobileNumber' does not belong to table .
```

It seems that the rows didnt copy properly, in Result dataTable.

whats the wrong with this code?

and I tried `Result.Rows.Add(dr);` instead of `Result.ImportRow(dr);`
but an exception throw with this information:

```
This row already belongs to another table.
```

Thanks for any helping...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making new `datatable Result` without any column. So, make sure you are bringing all columns from the table which you are going to copy.
In your case, you can clone the `TransactionDataTable` and then import the row.

The updated copy implementation will be like this :

```
    DataTable Result = TransactionDataTable.Clone();
    for(int i = 5; i < PageSize && i < TransactionDataTable.Rows.Count ; i++)
    {
        DataRow dr = (DataRow)TransactionDataTable.Rows[i];

        Result.ImportRow(dr);
    }

    string MobileNumber = TransactionDataTable.Rows[0]["MobileRegistration_MobileNumber"].ToString();
    string MobileNumber2 = Result.Rows[0]["MobileRegistration_MobileNumber"].ToString();
```